# Observable operators to "do" something after an amount of time has passed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In an rxjs observable chain, how could I do something with access to the current value of the observable after a set amount of time has passed? Essentially I am looking for something like the [tap operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) but that only executes if a set amount of time has passed without seeing a value from the observable. So really it's like a combination of tap and timeout.

I'm imagining something like the following

```
observable$.pipe(
  first(x => x > 5),
  tapAfterTime(2000, x => console.log(x)),
  map(x => x + 1)
).subscribe(...);
```

This is a made up example, and the "tapAfterTime" function isn't real. But the basic idea is that if 2000ms pass after subscribing and the observable hasn't seen a value greater than 5, then do the tapAfterTime callback function on whatever the current value of the observable is. If we saw a value greater than 5 before 2000ms then the tapAfterTime callback would never run, but the map function would always run as expected.

Is there an operator to achieve this or any combination of operators?

Comment: Should it run each 2000ms interval of silence or only once after previous x>5 emitted value?

Comment: Oh, since it contains 'first' it should run once i guess

Comment: debounceTime https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html or debounce https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debounce.html?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is really over complicated, maybe it is worth looking.

The idea is to have 2 different observables, created transforming the source `observable$` and then eventually merged.

The first Observable, let's call it `obsFilterAndMapped`, is the one where you do your filtering and mapping.

The second Observable, let's call it `obsTapDelay`, is an Observable which fires a new timer with a certain *delay* any time the first Observable, i.e. `obsFilterAndMapped`, emits - once the *delayTime* is passed then you perform your `tapAfterTime` action - if the first Observable emits a new value before the *delayTime* is passed, then a new timer is created.

This is the code that implements this idea

```
const stop = new Subject<any>();
const obsShared = observable$.pipe(
    finalize(() => {
        console.log('STOP');
        stop.next();
        stop.complete()
    }),
    share()
);
const delayTime = 300;
const tapAfterTime = (value) => {
    console.log('tap with delay', value)
}; 

let valueEmitted;

const obsFilterAndMapped = obsShared.pipe(
    tap(val => valueEmitted = val),
    filter(i => i > 7),
    map(val => val + ' mapped')
);

const startTimer = merge(of('START'), obsFilterAndMapped);

const obsTapDelay = startTimer.pipe(
    switchMap(val => timer(delayTime).pipe(
        tap(() => tapAfterTime(valueEmitted)),
        switchMap(() => empty()),
    )),
    takeUntil(stop),
)

merge(obsFilterAndMapped, obsTapDelay)
.subscribe(console.log, null, () => console.log('completed'))
```

With this approach you would perform youe `tapAfterTime` action any time the source `observable$` does not emit anything for a time longer than `delayTime`. In other words this would work not only for the first emission of `observable$` but for its entire life.

You can test such code with the following input

```
const obs1 = interval(100).pipe(
    take(10),
);
const obs2 = timer(2000, 100).pipe(
    take(10),
    map(val => val + 200),
);
const observable$ = merge(obs1, obs2);
```

With some more work we can even think to hide the `valueEmitted` global variable within a closure, but this would increase the complexity of the code and probably it is not worth.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

- https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html
- https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html

And possibly something like this?

--

```
initiateTimer() {
    if (this.timerSub) {
        this.timerSub.unsubscribe();
    }

    this.timerSub = Rx.Observable.timer(2000)
        .take(1)
        .subscribe(this.showPopup.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be something like this:

```
let cancel;
observable$.pipe(
  tap((x)=>clear=setTimeout(()=>console.log(x), 2000)),
   filter(x => x > 5),
   tap(x => clearTimeout(clear)),
   map(x => x + 1)
);
```

Comment: More about operators in RxJS in my video-course: https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/hands-rxjs-web-development-video